# "I'm calling to..." vs. "I called to..."

Tags: usage

Are the following two sentences both grammatically correct? Which one sounds more natural? I search both **I called to confirm** and **I'm calling to confirm** in Google books and both generate a lot of search results.

- I called to confirm with you about dinner on Friday.
- I'm calling to confirm with you about dinner on Friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one (I called to confirm) is past tense, so you must be talking about something that has already happened. The second one (I'm calling to confirm) is for something that's happening in that moment. For example:

> "Why did you call me before?"
>
> "I called to confirm..."

or you could have a conversation on the phone:

> "Why are you calling?"
>
> "I'm calling to confirm..."

I think both of your phrases are fine in informal English: spoken out loud, they would sound natural to me. In written English, I think 'confirm with you about' is not quite right, and I recommend "confirm with you *that* [something is happening]" rather than "confirm with you *about* something. If you wanted to use 'about', say 'talk to you about' instead.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is correct, in my opinion.  I would say "I'm calling to confirm my dinner reservation with you on Friday," if you're calling a restaurant, or "I'm calling to confirm that you will be joining me for dinner on Friday," if you're calling a friend or acquaintance.

Comment: By "not correct", do you mean not natural or not grammatical? OP asked about both.

Comment: It's not a natural way to phrase a question.  The specific problem is in the phrase "confirm with you about".  You can confirm a thing or talk about it, but you cannot confirm about a thing.

Answer (score 1):

"*I'm calling to confirm with you about dinner on Friday*" is 100% correct and natural.

The other one is in the simple past, so it means you called before, which cannot possibly refer to the current call.

Another possibility is "*I've called to confirm...*". This works because present perfect means the result of the past action is in the present. In this case, the past action is calling, and the present result is we're talking on the phone.